# Removing row DataGridView from x to y

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

So as the question say, is it possible to delete row from a to b I've tried a couple things like this one

```
        Dim dgv As DataGridViewRowCollection = DataGridView1.Rows

    For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In dgv
        Console.WriteLine(rw.Index)
        If (rw.Index > iNbrRow) Then
            If (Not rw.IsNewRow) Then
                Console.WriteLine("Delete : " & rw.Index)
                'dgv.RemoveAt(rw.Index)
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

But the problem is every time a row is deleted the index change so it doN,t delete all of them

P.S : iNbrRow = number of row - 2 who's initialized at form load

Thankcx hope you guys can help :S

Comment: Why did you tag both c# and vb?  Clearly this is VB.

Comment: @paqogomez I removed it I guss I just clicked too fast or somethings, my bad

Comment: You can also select them all with linq and remove them in one fell swoop.  `dgv.Where(rw => rw.Index > iNbrRow && !rw.IsNewRow);`

Comment: I'm not enought familiar with Linq to understand the statement but I will look into it thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't happen if you start at the end of the gridview and go backward:

```
For i As Integer = gView1.Rows.Count-1 To 0 Step -1
  If i > iNbrRow then
    ' delete the row
  end if
Next i
```

Comment: No problem -- we get used to "for each" and forget about the direction.